# Return cities based off state Google Maps api

Tags: google-maps

Does anybody know which Google Maps api service would be ideal for retrieving cities based off a selected state. For example if a user selects California from a select input.

```
<select name="state">
   <option value="CA" selected>California</option>
</select>
```

I would like preferably an ajax request to be made that would return all the cities in California and then append those values to a select input.

```
<select name="city">
   <option value="Los Angeles">Los Angeles</option>
   // Other California cities 
</select>
```

Or is there another service that anyone recommends for this type of functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately filtering by states is not possible in Google Maps API.

## Places Library

> The functions in the Google Places JavaScript library enable your application to search for places (defined in this API as establishments, geographic locations, or prominent points of interest) contained within a defined area, such as the bounds of a map, or around a fixed point.
>
> The Google Places API offers an autocomplete feature which you can use to give your applications the type-ahead-search behavior of the Google Maps search field. When a user starts typing an address, autocomplete will fill in the rest. For more information, see the [autocomplete documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete).

According to [**Component Filtering**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ComponentFiltering)

> You can also set the Geocoding Service to return address results restricted to a specific area. Specify the restriction by using the [`componentRestrictions`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GeocoderComponentRestrictions) parameter. A filter consists of one or more of: **`route`**, **`locality`**, **`administrativeArea`**, **`postalCode`** or **`country`**. Only results matching all the filters will be returned. Filter values support the same methods of spelling correction and partial matching as other geocoding requests.

Now to limit autocomplete to cities:

> `type`
>
> - Restricts the results to places matching the specified type. Only one type may be specified (if more than one type is provided, all types following the first entry are ignored). See the [list of supported types](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types).

Try this [sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-hotelsearch)

Component Filter

```
var map, places, infoWindow;
var markers = [];
var autocomplete;
var countryRestrict = {'country': 'us'};
```

Type Restriction

```
document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
        types: ['(cities)'],
        componentRestrictions: countryRestrict
      });
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: I was able to get what I wanted through the sba gov website. They have an api that will return cities based off the abbreviated state parameter you pass in the url. For example, the following would return all the cities in the state of California. You can specify if you want the data returned in xml or json by the extension provided right after the state abbreviation code. Try the following from terminal.  `curl http://api.sba.gov/geodata/city_links_for_state_of/CA.json`